# Send multiline argument to OptionParser

Tags: ruby, rspec, newline, optionparser

I have `.rspec` file in my project with content something like this:
`--exclude-pattern spec/1_spec.rb, spec/2_spec.rb`
There is pretty long line of specs, so I want to split this to several lines, but don't know how.
`--exclude-pattern spec/1_spec.rb, \
spec/2_spec.rb`

seems not working, `rspec` command give error:

`Unmatched double quote: "--exclude-pattern 'spec/1_spec.rb,`

What line separator should I use?

UPDATE:
I found out, that [rspec uses OptionParser](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/master/lib/rspec/core/option_parser.rb#L40) to parse those arguments.
So I can rephrase my question:
How to send multiline argument to OptionParser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you know that you can use ERB in this file? Given you have a `excluded_files.txt` file in the same directory with contents:

```
spec/1_spec.rb
spec/2_spec.rb
```

You can write your `.rspec` this way:

```
--exclude-pattern <%= File.readlines('excluded_files.txt').map(&:strip).join(', ') %>
```

This should result to a single string of excluded files separated by commas.

P.S. Maybe you should use [tags](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-0/docs/command-line/tag-option) instead?

Comment: I didn't know, but I think those code is pretty hard to read, and I don't want to add separate file to project.   I think I leave my old code if there is no alternatives.

Comment: Oh, I like your idea with tags, I think I will use it